# Invalid SQL Command in JavaFx application

Tags: java, sql

I want to import data from excel file to MySQL Database using Java. I use for activity to read each row and insert it to database. After the first iterration, I get an error Invalid SQL Command. First record is inserted in database. Please help me with this issue. Bellow is my java code. Thanks.

```
public void importXLtoDB()  {
        String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO employee (dbSurname, dbName, dbBirthDate, dbEmail, dbMobile, dbPabx, " +
                "dbDepartment, dbTeam, dbCurrentPosition, dbManager) VALUE (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        try {


        connection = database.getConnection();
        pst = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);

            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                    new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Excel Files", "*.xlsx", "*.xls"));
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fileIn);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row;
        for (int i=1; i<= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(i);
            java.util.Date utilDate = row.getCell(2).getDateCellValue();
            java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
            pst.setString(1, row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
            pst.setString(2, row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
            pst.setDate(3, sqlDate);
            pst.setString(4, row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue());
            pst.setString(5, row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
            pst.setString(6, row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue());
            pst.setString(7, row.getCell(6).getStringCellValue());
            pst.setString(8, row.getCell(7).getStringCellValue());
            pst.setString(9, row.getCell(8).getStringCellValue());
            pst.setString(10, row.getCell(9).getStringCellValue());

            pst.execute();
        }
            NotificationType notificationType = NotificationType.INFORMATION;
            TrayNotification tray = new TrayNotification();
            tray.setTitle("Information Message");
            tray.setMessage("Employees Details Imported to Database");
            tray.setNotificationType(notificationType);
            tray.showAndDismiss(Duration.millis(3000));

            wb.close();
            fileIn.close();
            pst.close();
            rs.close();

    }catch (SQLException e) {
            NotificationType notificationType = NotificationType.ERROR;
            TrayNotification tray = new TrayNotification();
            tray.setTitle("Warning Message Dialog");
            tray.setMessage("Invalid SQL Command");
            tray.setNotificationType(notificationType);
            tray.showAndDismiss(Duration.millis(3000));
        }catch (IOException e) {
            NotificationType notificationType = NotificationType.ERROR;
            TrayNotification tray = new TrayNotification();
            tray.setTitle("Warning Message Dialog");
            tray.setMessage("The System cannot find de file");
            tray.setNotificationType(notificationType);
            tray.showAndDismiss(Duration.millis(3000));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have changed to VALUES and got the same error - Invalid SQL Commnad and first record was inserted and others not

Comment: So what has this question to do with JavaFX? It is a pure Java question.

Comment: Try using `pst.executeQuery`, as I have pointed out in my updated answer.

Comment: i changed to `pst.executeQuery` and i got the same error but now the first record wasn't inserted

Comment: unrelated to fx

Comment: @Adrian I've updated my answer. Check if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax should be:

```
INSERT INTO employee (dbSurname, dbName, dbBirthDate, dbEmail, dbMobile, dbPabx, dbDepartment, dbTeam, dbCurrentPosition, dbManager) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

It's `VALUES`, not `VALUE`

Futhermore, you should be executing your command as an update. So you should replace `pst.execute()` with `pst.executeQuery()`

If that doesn't work, try adding this block of code `pst = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);` into the for loop.

It should look like this inside the for loop:

```
    pst = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
    row = sheet.getRow(i);
    java.util.Date utilDate = row.getCell(2).getDateCellValue();
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
    pst.setString(1, row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
    pst.setString(2, row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
    pst.setDate(3, sqlDate);
    pst.setString(4, row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue());
    pst.setString(5, row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
    pst.setString(6, row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue());
    pst.setString(7, row.getCell(6).getStringCellValue());
    pst.setString(8, row.getCell(7).getStringCellValue());
    pst.setString(9, row.getCell(8).getStringCellValue());
    pst.setString(10, row.getCell(9).getStringCellValue());

    pst.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Solved. I changed Charset in MySQL Database to utf8

Comment: Congratulations!